# PHP equivalent for Excel's COMBIN(N,K) function?

Tags: php, math, combinations, combinatorics

I am aware that the function may be computed manually using factorials, the problem is that larger numbers will not calculate properly.

For example, if I input `COMBIN(1500,5)` in MS Excel it will return `62,860,358,437,800` as it should. But if I try to calculate it manually, even in Excel I will get a `#NUM!` error when I try to first find the factorial of 1500. The manual formula would be

> 1500!/5!(1500-5)!

I find it curious that Excel's COMBIN function calculates properly yet the manual way returns an error. In short, I am wondering if there is an equivalent of this function in PHP? I have already tried manually computing using gmp_fact and as with Excel, it returns error (`NaN`).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is failing because you're quickly overflowing the `Integer` data type, which is probably just 32-bits on your system. You could use the arbitrary precision math functions to get around that problem:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php

If `gmp_fact(...)` seems to be returning errors or bad results, you're probably passing it a bad value or assuming it's result is a basic numeric type. You'll want to use something like `gmp_strval` to convert the returned GMP resource into something readable when you're done performing calculations.

Example:

```
$a = gmp_fact(1500);
$b = gmp_fact(5);
$c = gmp_fact(1500-5);
$result = gmp_div($a,(gmp_mul($b,$c)));
echo gmp_strval($result);
```

Comment: `echo gmp_strval(gmp_fact(1500))/gmp_strval(gmp_fact(5))*gmp_strval(gmp_fact(1500-5));` returns `INF`

Comment: The numbers are extraordinarily long so I can see why it's producing errors, just wondering how Excel's function works so well and if there is a possible PHP equivalent.

Comment: You need to use `gmp_` functions until you're done with your calculation. Specifically, you need to use `gmp_div` and `gmp_mul` instead of `/` and `*`. And only use `gmp_strval` on the final value returned by all those function calls. I'll update the original answer with an example.

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense since `gmp_` is an extension. Thanks.